# How to parse only the first level of nested tags with regex?

Tags: php, regex

Say I have a block of text like this:

```
<item>
   foo bar foo bar 
   <item> child item </item>
</item>
<item>
   second item
   <item> second child </item>
</item>
```

Here, what I want is to parse only the two top levels of `<item>`s to be parsed, and the result returned to me in an array like this:

```
[0] = "foo bar foo bar  <item>child item</item>"
[1] = "second item  <item>second child </item>";
```

However in my testing, since the child level `<item>` tags match the pattern, they are also included and I get a 4 element array rather than a 2 element array as I want.

This is the pattern I've used:

```
%<item>(.+)</item>%si
```

Any ideas?

**Edit: This is NOT for HTML, its for a custom, in-house scripting language for which I can't use any dom parsers. So please suggest a regex solution.**

Comment: The real answer here is to not use regexes to look through html. There are html parsers that will make this much much easier, and less error prone.

Comment: This isn't for HTML, its for a custom scripting language and I can't use any DOM parsers.

Comment: What does "custom scripting language" mean. You are saying that those are not paragraph HTML element tags?

Comment: @jeroen Its only one block of text from a scripting language for allowing non-technical users to specify some rules. Its custom built. I've already tried and can't use any dom parsers. I need to do this via regex.

Comment: How about an xml parser?

Comment: @thatidiotguy no, those aren't html tags, there are a lot of other tags put in there like `[if] [else]` etc, it has only 20% in common with HTML.

Comment: @jeroen Unfortunately no, its not structured XML as you can see from the example

Comment: If you really want to go this route, look into recursive patterns then `(?R)`. Also note that there is a difference between "parsing" and "matching".

Comment: @mario If you'd like to post an answer detailing those a bit, I'll accept it.

Comment: Are the `<`, `>` and `/` characters escaped in the content (and how)?

Comment: `its for a custom, in-house scripting language for which I can't use any dom parsers` - what language is it built in? Is there no way you can utilise libxml within it?

Comment: @jeroen Nothing is escaped in the content provided by users.

Comment: Then you're bound to fail if a user decides to use these characters in the content / your users can break your application :-(

Comment: @mario It won't let me add a bounty before 48 hours. But if you post a solution to this problem, I'll award it a bounty as soon as it lets me

Comment: I was primarily trying to coerce you into googling.

Comment: @mario I am googling it, but if you post an answer, then this question will be complete for others in future who might come across it

Answer (score 3):

```
%<p>(.+?)^</p>%smi
```

edit

```
$text = "<item> foo bar foo bar <item> child item </item> </item> <item> second item <item> second child </item> </item>";
preg_match_all('%<item>(.*?<item>.*?</item>).*?</item>%si', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

output

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  foo bar foo bar <item> child item </item>
    [1] =>  second item <item> second child </item>
)
```

Comment: It works, however if I shift the lines around to put all the tags on the same line for example, then it stops working..

Comment: You keep moving the goalpost :P

Comment: If I put in more than one nested `<item>` tags inside a main `<item>` then it fails again.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is not well suited to what you are doing. If you pursue this route, you will probably spend more time on it than if you just go a different route. I suggest you check out a DOM parser. The one below is fairly easy to use, and should work for your basic needs.

[PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Also check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php), since it will give you additional alternatives.

Comment: This isn't for HTML, its for a custom scripting language and I can't use any DOM parsers.

Comment: Can you post a real example of a full section of this custom language?

Comment: That's not relavant to this question. I've posted what's relavant to what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You say the input is not HTML, but provided a string that looks like HTML. See, regex works best on plain text, not a marked-up text. You do not reveal what the real language lies behind this type of input, so, the solution I can suggest is based on the *assumption that the `<` char cannot appear as a literal in-between element nodes* (only as some entity).

That means, you might use a *negated character class* `[^<]` and apply the `*` quantifier to it:

```
%<item>([^<]+)</item>%i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VzAoAa/1),  [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/Irl1lN):

```
$text = "<item> foo bar foo bar <item> child item </item> </item> <item> second item <item> second child </item> </item>";
preg_match_all('%<item>([^<]*)<item>%i', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
// => Array ( [0] =>  foo bar foo bar  [1] =>  second item )
```